# Title image alignment in toolbar android

Tags: android

Why image in toolbar not align in center when remove the menu items in android.
If i have hide the menu items the title moved right.that is some spaces added between navigation icon and title.

My code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
android:background="#FFF">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:id="@+id/pg_title"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/logo"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Please put your code here so we can see what you are doing, and can help you in a better way after.

Answer (score 1):

try this add this **toolbar** in your **layout xml** file

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

create a new **actionbar_layout** for your toolbar like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bike" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**now in your activity file just add below code**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: thank you for ur reply yeah i also add the tool bar like as ur code. i have use fragements  for first fragment the toolbar have menu items so the title align center correctly. when i remove or set invisible to the menu items. the title is not align center.